# apparmor denies to mount /run for lxc-start

Tags: ubuntu, security, lxc, container, apparmor

I am trying to set up a privileged container on Ubuntu where apparmor denies to mount `/run` `/run/lock` and /`sys/fs/cgroup` while running `lxc-start`.

**Violations**

```
[ 1621.278919] audit: type=1400 audit(1499177276.634:12): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="/usr/bin/lxc-start" name="/run/" pid=2097 comm="systemd" fstype="tmpfs" srcname="tmpfs" flags="rw, nosuid, nodev, strictatime"
[ 1621.302331] audit: type=1400 audit(1499177276.658:13): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="/usr/bin/lxc-start" name="/run/lock/" pid=2097 comm="systemd" fstype="tmpfs" srcname="tmpfs" flags="rw, nosuid, nodev, noexec"
[ 1621.325944] audit: type=1400 audit(1499177276.682:14): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed flags match" error=-13 profile="/usr/bin/lxc-start" name="/sys/fs/cgroup/" pid=2097 comm="systemd" fstype="tmpfs" srcname="tmpfs" flags="rw, nosuid, nodev, noexec, strictatime"
```

`lxc-start --version`: 2.0.6

Kernel version: 4.9

Any hints?

Comment: Are you looking to deny them or is apparmor automatically denying them and you want to allow them?

Comment: @RamanSailopal : Apparmor is automatically denying these mounts for the `lxc-start` profile and I want apparmor to allow them. I haven't changed anything in the `usr.bin.lxc-start` apparmor profile,It's the default one which came along with the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Install the apparmor-utils package and then kick off two sessions to the server. In one session, run:

```
genprof /usr/bin/lxc-start
```

In the other, actually run the process. The genprof session will then prompt you for what you actually want the process to have access to.

Comment: Would be nice for people to actually add comments as to why they have down voted!

Answer (score 0):

Just as Raman Sailopal said - genprof can help here. Thou it's `aa-genprof <path to application>`

```
$ sudo aa-genprof /usr/bin/lxc-start
```